# Категоризация числового ряда по матрице чувствительности

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, матрицы, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить корректно датафрейм таким образом, чтобы после через заданную функцию выбирать в какую категорию попадает то либо иное значение:

Имеется S0, S1, S2, S2. Согласно матрице чувствительности (картинка внизу) необходимо написать функцию, которая будет определять в какую категорию S попадет "исследуемый" если он отвечает параметрам согласно картинки внизу: например исследуемый имеет 250 000 Евро кредитов и у него Grade 3 - следовательно он попадает под категорию S0. 
Или другой пример: исследуемый имеет кредит на сумму 1 500 000 и grade 5 - следовательно он попадает под категорию S2

Пытаюсь это сделать в виде датафрейма с заданием cat, но совсем ничего не выходит. Буду очень признателен за помощь!

матрица чувствительности:
[image: 9dyb]

Comment: можете привести данную матрицу чувствительности заполненную S0, S1, S2, S3 (вместо цветов) в виде CSV файла или выложить в виде Excel файла? Так чтобы мы могли легко прочитать данную матрицу...

Comment: Буду признателен если подскажите как предоставить xls файл?

Comment: привести ссылку на любой свободный файлообменник ;)

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/oq5JJRmUGKxPTw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть нам дана следующая матрица чувствительности:

```
  Grade 1-10 11-30 31-60 61-100
0     1   S0    S0    S0     S1
1     2   SO    S0    S1     S1
2     3   S0    S1    S1     S2
3     4   S1    S1    S2     S3
4     5   S1    S2    S2     S3
5    na   S0    S1    S3     S3
```

PS все столбцы имеют строковой тип данных (`object`)

преобразуем ее к следующему виду:

```
m = m.set_index('Grade').stack().rename_axis(['Grade', 'Range']).to_frame('Cat')

In [200]: m
Out[200]:
             Cat
Grade Range
1     1-10    S0
      11-30   S0
      31-60   S0
      61-100  S1
2     1-10    SO
      11-30   S0
      31-60   S1
...           ..
5     11-30   S2
      31-60   S2
      61-100  S3
na    1-10    S0
      11-30   S1
      31-60   S3
      61-100  S3

[24 rows x 1 columns]
```

Далее пусть нам дан DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':np.random.randint(100, size=100), 
                   'Grade':np.random.choice('1 2 3 4 5 na'.split(), size=100)})

In [213]: df
Out[213]:
    val Grade
0    21     4
1    82    na
2    26    na
3     8     2
4    58     5
5    35     1
6    37    na
..  ...   ...
93    5     5
94   39     2
95   31     2
96   75     4
97   88     1
98    5     3
99   28    na

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

теперь создадим новый технический столбец с нужными диапазонами чисел:

```
bins = [0, 11, 31, 61, 100]
labels = '1-10 11-30 31-60 61-100'.split()
df['Range'] = pd.cut(df['val'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

получилось:

```
In [215]: df
Out[215]:
    val Grade   Range
0    21     4   11-30
1    82    na  61-100
2    26    na   11-30
3     8     2    1-10
4    58     5   31-60
5    35     1   31-60
6    37    na   31-60
..  ...   ...     ...
93    5     5    1-10
94   39     2   31-60
95   31     2   11-30
96   75     4  61-100
97   88     1  61-100
98    5     3    1-10
99   28    na   11-30

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

теперь эти два Dataframe можно связать по столбцам `['Grade','Range'])`:

```
res = df.merge(m, on=['Grade','Range'])
```

результат:

```
In [219]: res
Out[219]:
    val Grade   Range Cat
0    21     4   11-30  S1
1    26     4   11-30  S1
2    29     4   11-30  S1
3    82    na  61-100  S3
4    66    na  61-100  S3
5    88    na  61-100  S3
6    91    na  61-100  S3
..  ...   ...     ...  ..
93   52     3   31-60  S1
94   56     3   31-60  S1
95   60     3   31-60  S1
96   40     3   31-60  S1
97   43     2   31-60  S1
98   39     2   31-60  S1
99   88     1  61-100  S1

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Схожий ответ использующий предоставленную матрицу с автоматическим созданием списка диапазонов.

```
mx = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\matrix.xls').astype(str)

labels = mx.columns.drop('Grade')
bins = (pd.to_numeric(labels.to_series().str.split('-').str[0].str.replace(r'[>=]*',''),
                      errors='coerce')
          .tolist() + [np.inf])

print('Labels:', labels)
# Labels: Index(['1-150000', '150001-200000', '200001-300000', '300001-500000', '500001-750000', '750001-1000000', '1000001-1500000',
#        '1500001-5000000', '5000001-10000000', '10000001-20000000', '>=20000001'],
#       dtype='object')

print('Bins:', bins)
# Bins: [1, 150001, 200001, 300001, 500001, 750001, 1000001, 1500001, 5000001, 10000001, 20000001, inf]


# "UNPIVOT"-ing матрицы чувствительности
mx = mx.set_index('Grade').stack().rename_axis(['Grade', 'Range']).to_frame('Cat')
```

---

```
In [260]: mx
Out[260]:
                        Cat
Grade Range
1     1-150000           S0
      150001-200000      S0
      200001-300000      S0
      300001-500000      S1
      500001-750000      S1
      750001-1000000     S1
      1000001-1500000    S1
...                      ..
na    500001-750000      S2
      750001-1000000     S3
      1000001-1500000    S3
      1500001-5000000    S3
      5000001-10000000   S3
      10000001-20000000  S3
      >=20000001         S3

[121 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

Исходный DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':np.random.randint(20*10**6, size=1000),
                   'Grade':np.random.choice('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 na'.split(), size=1000)})
```

создадим новый технический столбец с нужными диапазонами чисел:

```
df['Range'] = pd.cut(df['val'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

In [261]: df
Out[261]:
          val Grade              Range
0    19766801     4  10000001-20000000
1    13094011     7  10000001-20000000
2    14851266    10  10000001-20000000
3     5654832     9   5000001-10000000
4    15025214     4  10000001-20000000
5    12438160     6  10000001-20000000
6    14329828     3  10000001-20000000
..        ...   ...                ...
993   3431253     1    1500001-5000000
994  12464364     3  10000001-20000000
995   7555289    na   5000001-10000000
996  18055241    10  10000001-20000000
997  14982569    na  10000001-20000000
998  11081472     2  10000001-20000000
999    756551    na     750001-1000000

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

объединение DataFrame's:

```
res = df.merge(mx, on=['Grade','Range'])
```

результат:

```
In [317]: pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)

In [318]: res
Out[318]:
          val Grade              Range Cat
0    19766801     4  10000001-20000000  S3
1    15025214     4  10000001-20000000  S3
2    16982796     4  10000001-20000000  S3
3    17944861     4  10000001-20000000  S3
4    16368003     4  10000001-20000000  S3
5    12421311     4  10000001-20000000  S3
6    11796631     4  10000001-20000000  S3
7    15107141     4  10000001-20000000  S3
8    17687879     4  10000001-20000000  S3
9    18543342     4  10000001-20000000  S3
..        ...   ...                ...  ..
990    715893     2      500001-750000  S1
991   1348150     4    1000001-1500000  S2
992   1411619     4    1000001-1500000  S2
993   1145865     4    1000001-1500000  S2
994    308014     9      300001-500000  S2
995    308776     9      300001-500000  S2
996   1405776     6    1000001-1500000  S3
997    328975     5      300001-500000  S1
998    579072    10      500001-750000  S2
999    756551    na     750001-1000000  S3

[1000 rows x 4 columns]
```